# Azure Devops : YAML Pipeline for independent Deployment of Single Tenant .Net MVC App for different clients

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need suggestions for creating a YAML pipeline for the independent deployment of the Single Tenant .Net MVC App for different clients.

- Application Type: .Net MVC Web API
- Web Server: IIS 10
- Database: MS SQL Server
- Environment: Private Data Center
- Number of Clients/tenant: 150+
- Deployment: For each client/tenant, a separate IIS Web App is created. Also, a separate database is created for each client.
- Expected Deployment: Manual mode (Not considering CD because CI and test suite are not available yet).

If you can guide me about the following points.

- How pipeline should be created in such a way that I can use different configuration parameters per client/tenant? (e.g. Database name and connection string) But at the same time, the common script for the deployment of generated release?
- Should I create a single pipeline or there should be multiple?
- How I should use release, stage, jobs effectively for such a scenario?
- If I get some good articles for manual independent deployment for each client, I would like to study.

Comment: Hi @sandippatel2002, How are things going? Is the latest suggestion in my answer helpful to you? Please check with it. Any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you want to deploy to different environments, you can set up a stage for each environment in a pipeline. However, considering that you have 150+ different configurations, it is so torturous to set up 150+ stages in the pipeline.

If all the deployments have the same deployment steps (same scripts, same input parameters), but different values of the input parameters, you can try using [**Multi-job configuration**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#multi-job-configuration) (the [**Matrix**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#strategies)) in the pipeline.

With this way, you do not need to set up a stage or a job for each configurations, you just need to set up a stage or a job with all the common deployment steps. But you need to enumerate all the configurations (150+) you require. When running the pipeline, it will generate 150+ matrix jobs with the same deployment steps but different values of the input parameters.

**[UPDATE]**

> Just curious, in this case of multi-job configuration, all the 150+ installations will be triggered in one go, right?

After the pipeline run is triggered, all the 105+ matrix jobs will be triggered and be in queue. However, normally not all the 150+ jobs will be started up to run in parallel at the same time. It depends on the **`maxParallel`** you set and how many available agents can be assigned to the run.

> I can't select the way, where deployment is started for let's say 5 of the client only.

If you want that the deployment can be executed firstly for some clients and then for other clients, you can try using stages.

For example, in `stage_1`, execute the deployment job (multi-job configuration) for the first 5 clients. After `stage_1`, start up `stage_2` for another several clients, then `stage_3` for other clients, etc..

You can use the **`dependsOn`** key to set the execution order of the stages, and use **`condition`** key to set a stage only runs when the specified condition is met.

To view more details, you can see "[**Add stages, dependencies, & conditions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)".

Comment: Thanks! I will look into multi-job configuration. Just curious, in this case of multi-job configuration, all the 150+ installations will be triggered in one go, right? I can't select the way, where deployment is started for let's say 5 of the client only.

Comment: Hi @sandippatel2002, I have updated my answer with more detailed explanation and suggestion. Please check it. Any questions about this, feel free to contact me.